# OVER clause in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this data:

```
Empid   Designation         
------------------------------------
17791   Assistant Manager   
19624   Assistant Manager   
19624   Assistant Manager   
19748   Assistant Manager   
19758   Graduate Engineer Trainee
```

I want the output as below:

```
Designation             Count
------------------------------
Assistant Manager         4
Graduate Engineer Trainee 1
```

Please suggest how can we get it without subquery

Thanks

Comment: please show your attempt and explain what's not working

Comment: I have tried the below

select designation,sum(mycount)mycount from (
SELECT EMPID,DESIGNATION,COUNT(DESIGNATION)OVER(PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY EMPID)mycount FROM mytable )x
group by designation

But I want without subquery

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a very simple grouping operation - how about this:

```
SELECT
    Designation, COUNT(*)
FROM
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
GROUP BY
    Designation
```